# Jquery replaceWith:replace one php file with another php file based on screen resolution

Tags: php, jquery, replace

I need to be able to replace a php file with another php file based on screen resolution. This is what I have so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function adjustStyle(width) {
width = parseInt(width);
if (width = 1920) {
$('book.php').replaceWith('book2.php');
}
}
$(function() {
adjustStyle($(this).width());
$(window).resize(function() {
adjustStyle($(this).width());
});
});
</script>
```

which obviously isn't working-- any ideas? Thank you in advance for any help received.

***UPDATE***

Is this at all close (to replace the book.php line)?

```
 { $("a[href*='book.php']").replaceWith('href', 'book2.php'); };
```

***Second Update to reflect input gathered here***

```
function adjustStyle(width) {
width = parseInt(width);
if (width == 1920) {
$('#bookinfo').replaceWith(['book2.php']);
$.ajax({
 url: "book2.php",
 }).success(function ( data ) {
  $('#bookinfo').replaceWith(data);
});
$(function() {
adjustStyle($(this).width());
$(window).resize(function() {
adjustStyle($(this).width());
});
});
}
}
```

Comment: Screen *resolution* or screen *pixel-size*, they're *not* the same thing.

Comment: screen resolution- the part I am hung up on is the correct way to write this line: $('book.php').replaceWith('book2.php'); which obviously replaces the first php file with the second

Comment: I don't think, or can't see how, your comment answers my question.

Comment: Two things. You use if(width = 1920). If you do this, then it only works when the width is exactly 1920. Second is that you should make a comparison, ie if(width == 1920){}

Comment: @Daniel- yes, only for 1920 and yes I know-- I condensed the code down to focus on the area I actually need help with which, again, is this: $('book.php').replaceWith('book2.php');

Comment: This whole concept just destroys the notion of progressive enhancement.  It's pure "UI brute forcing a solution" at its finest.....

Answer (score 1):

I have not seen the use of replaceWith in the context you put it in. Interpreting that you want to exchange the content, you may want to do so my using the load() function of jQuery.

```
    if(width == 1920){
            $("#myDiv").load("book1.php");
    } else {
            $("#myDiv").load("book2.php");
    }
```

Clicking on the button replaces the content of the div to book2.php.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but I have a php file that processes and displays a certain amount of results and need to be able to replace that file with another php file that processes and displays more or less results based on screen resolution. Replacing the files seems to be the best option- I do not want visitors to the page to even know anything was changed.

Comment: Other than using an if statement, I believe it should work fine for you. That is, unless you want to do more in the background. This simply loads either file you like and is the most simplified form for an ajax interaction. You read the clients width and decide what file to load.
I have edited the code to reflect on this.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem is I don't think that you are using the correct selectors. If you have the following container:

`<div id="bookContainer">Contents of book1.php</div>`

The code to replace the contents of that container should be

`$('#bookContainer').replaceWith([contents of book2.php]);`

In order to get [contents of book2.php] you will need to pull it in by ajax using the following code I have also included the line above so that the data from book2.php will be placed into the container:

```
$.ajax({
 url: "http://yoururl.com/book2.php",
 }).success(function ( data ) {
  $('#bookContainer').replaceWith(data);
});.
```

I haven't tested this so there might be an issue but this is the concept you need to accomplish this.

Comment: I adjusted the code above-- can you tell me if it looks correct?

Comment: I would use the answer provided by Daniel. It is a simpler version of what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

First off... using a conditional with a single = (equal sign) will cause the condition to always be true while setting the value of variable your checking to the value your checking against.

Your condition should look like the following...

> if (width == 1920) { // do something }

Second, please refer to the jQuery documentation for how to replace the entire tag with a jquery object using replaceWith()... http://api.jquery.com/replaceWith/

I would use a shorthand POST with http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/ since you don't have the object loaded yet...

In short, my code would look like the following using $.post instead of $.ajax assuming I had a tag with the id of "book" that originally has the contents of book.php and I wanted to replace it with the contents of book2.php...

HTML

```
<div id="book">*Contents of book.php*</div>
```

jQuery

```
function onResize(width) {
    if (parseInt(width) >= 1920) {
        $.post('book2.php',function(html){
           $('#book').html(html).width(width);
        });        
    }
    else {
        $.post('book.php',function(html){
            $('#book').html(html).width(width);
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Won't both files still be called here? The book.php and book2.php? Not sure how this will work without replacing one for the other

Comment: if you want the div to start empty, then you wouldn't load the book.php into the html. I was assuming you already had book.php loaded. I'll update the script